# I am learning how to use grep and came across this. How does it work?

Tags: grep, pipe, tail

What would

```
grep '#' input.txt | tail -n
```

give me? I am new to this and cannot figure out what happens using `grep` and `tail` together.

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried it? What do you need explained?

Comment: `tail -n` is an error as the `-n` option to the `tail` utility takes a numerical argument, which is missing.

Comment: see also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '#' input.txt
```

this command will search the text from the file, in this case # will be searched in file input.txt and all occurrence will be printed on screen

then you used pipe sign that means do not print the output and pass the output to the next command written after pipe sign |

so

```
tail -n
```

it's incorrect, as tail -n needs some number so that it will print the number of lines that you mention with number from the bottom, i.e. tail -n 2 it will print last 2 lines

take this example, i have a file named input.txt with following content written in it:

```
[root@localhost student]# cat input.txt 
# this is a new line comment 1
this is not a comment line 1
this is not a comment line 2

# this is a new line comment 2
# this is a new line comment 3 
# this is a new line comment 4 
# this is a new line comment 5 
# this is a new line comment 6 
# this is a new line comment 7 
# this is a new line comment 8 
# this is a new line comment 9 
# this is a new line comment 10 

this is not a comment line 3
this is not a comment line 4
this is not a comment line 5
```

if you run the command

```
[root@localhost student]# grep '#' input.txt | tail -n 2
# this is a new line comment 9 
# this is a new line comment 10
```

it has searched the character in the file and may have found 10 lines then we further filtered it out and printed last 2 lines from that result by writing tail -n 2

hope it's clear to you now,